# npm WARN Invalid version in angular8

Tags: angular

When running command `npm install` then getting below error and packages is not being installed.

```
npm install
npm WARN Invalid version: "1.2.8.70"
npm WARN STA No description
npm WARN STA No repository field.
npm WARN STA No README data
npm WARN STA No license field
```

.
How to fix this problem in simplest way keeping the version number as mentioned.

## package.json

```
{
 "version": "1.2.8.70"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the [`semver (Semantic Versioning)`](https://semver.org/#semantic-versioning-200) rules.

A "version" is composed of three parts: `<major> "." <minor> "." <patch>`

- **MAJOR** version when you make incompatible API changes,
- **MINOR** version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
- **PATCH** version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

*Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.*

E.g.: `2.1.17`

NPM uses the `Semantic Versioning`, and the version you set doesn't match the semver rules. You need to adapt it like: `1.2.70` for example.